# SQL query to find names of employees belonging to particular department

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have created two tables one employee table and the other is department table .Employee table has fields `EmpId , Empname , DeptID , sal , Editedby and editedon` where

`EmpId` is the primary key and `Dept` table has `DeptID` and `deptname` where `DeptID` is the secondary key.

I want the SQL query to show names of employees belonging to software departmant 
The entries in dept table are as below :

```
DeptID Deptname
1      Software
2      Accounts
3      Administration 
4      Marine
```

Comment: This is a very simple one, try using `inner join` and you have a key `DeptID` joining emp and dept. If you get problem with the query let us know. I would suggest to try something first.

Comment: Hi , I tried using inner join but it gave me  a different output .

Comment: Try as `select e.* from employee e join department d on d.DeptID = e.DeptID where d.DeptID = 1` or `select e.* from employee e join department d on d.DeptID = e.DeptID where d.deptname = 'Software'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
      E.empname 
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN department D ON E.DeptID=D.DeptID
WHERE D.DeptID = '1'
```

Comment: Hi , I tried using inner join but it gave me a different output

Comment: the desired output is as below :   EmpName  :Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE DeptID = 1
```

Comment: @DipanjanaMukherjee:- Even if it works, it is not a recommended or suggested way with the table schema you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      E.empname 
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN department D ON E.DeptID=D.DeptID
where D.Deptname = 'Software'
```

Comment: @Dipanjana Mukherjee:- What is the output you are getting by using INNER JOIN?

Comment: i got d desired output using ur query . Thanks